# Problem Deploying .war on Tomcat 5 (Null pointer exception)

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, deployment, nullpointerexception

I prepare the .war file and deploy it on my topmcat server, but there is a problem with the servlets.

The problem everyone's usually having is the `ClassNotFoundException`, but this one is a `NullPointerException` and I couldn't find why. Thanks for your help.

I'm using jdk 1.5, my project is GWT 2.3.0, and tomcat is Tomcat 5.

The 365th line at Properties.java is `inLimit = inStream.read(inBuf);` where inStream(`InputStream`)  is the input parameter to the constructor of the class `LineReader`. The exception is thrown from the method `readLine()`.

Here's the stack trace:

```
- Marking servlet generalService as unavailable
- Allocate exception for servlet generalService
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:365)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:293)
        at com.cs.eyeks.gwt.core.EyeksGwtConf.<init>(EyeksGwtConf.java:17)
        at com.cs.eyeks.gwt.core.EyeksGwtConf.getConfiguration(EyeksGwtConf.java
:29)
        at com.cs.eyeks.gwt.EyeksGwtRemoteServiceServlet.<init>(EyeksGwtRemoteSe
rviceServlet.java:28)
        at tr.gov.gib.mhdb.vimer.vimerapp.server.GeneralServiceImpl.<init>(Gener
alServiceImpl.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:501)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.
java:1089)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.jav
a:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:151)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:870)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.p
rocessConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpo
int.java:528)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFol
lowerWorkerThread.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadP
ool.java:685)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: It seems properties file missing, can you check source code of properties file at `Properties.java:365`

Comment: Perhaps you can look at or add to your question line 365 of `Properties.java` since that is where the error occurred.  (I know it is in the JDK, but you can get the source to it.)

Comment: you mean jdk might be causing the problem? I'm using jdk 1.5, my project is GWT 2.3.0, and tomcat is Tomcat 5.

Comment: The 365th line at Properties.java is inLimit = inStream.read(inBuf); where inStream(InputStream) is the input parameter to the constructor of the class LineReader. The exception is thrown from the method readLine().

Comment: so that's gotta mean there's nothing to read, right? Could it be a problem with web.xml? But if the servlet mappings were wrong, wouldn't it raise a different error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EyeksGwtConf.java, line 17 tries to load a non-existing config file, or the filename for Properties is null.